# Sourcing files that are retrieved with app.get()

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js, I'm routing different directories in a site and am using app.get() to redirect traffic.

Problem: When using app.get(), the index.html file that is sent to the user thinks its directory is the root directory. But I have libraries that are in the sub-directory that aren't being reached.

Example:

```
app.get('/htmlFileInD1', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/root/D1/htmlFileInD1.html');
}
```

But in htmlFileInD1.html is:

```
<img class="wifi_battery" src="img/wifi_battery4.gif">
```

The image is being called from the root directory, but the img folder is in the D1 subdirectory.

I don't want to do:

```
<img class="wifi_battery" src="root/D1/img/wifi_battery4.gif">
```

since I have a lot of other libraries that I would have to change the source for.

What's the best way for the app.get() file to still call on its native directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serve your static assets like images by adding the following in your app

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/root/D1/'));
```

Comment: Does that go inside the app.get() method?

     app.get('/htmlFileInD1', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/root/D1/htmlFileInD1.html');
}

Comment: No, it goes outside of it. Put it before your `app.get()`

Comment: What if i'm already using `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/root/public'));` for a different set of `app.get()` 's?

Overall, I'm trying to route the site to different webpages depending on use-case. I have a public folder by default. But I want to setup an "experimental" directory for a different set of webpages (each which have their own required libraries).